# Substract 2 character lists

Tags: r, character

I have different character lists such as:

```
list1 <- c("abw", "afg", "ago", "aia", "alb", "and", "ant", "are", "arg", "arm", "asm", "ata", "atf")
list2 <- c("and", "ant")
list3 <- c("abw", "afg")
```

I would like to subtract the values contained in `list2` and `list3` from list1 to obtain the following result:

```
list.final <- c("ago", "aia", "alb", "are", "arg", "arm", "asm", "ata", "atf")
```

A "simple" `list.final <- list1-list2-list3` obviously does not work...

Any idea?

Comment: Try `list1[!list1 %in% list2]`

Comment: Specifically here, `list1[! list1 %in% c(list2, list3)]`. Note these are not lists, but rather character vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `setdiff` to remove elements from a vector. For example to remove `list2` from `list1`

```
setdiff(list1, list2)
```

and you can then again remove `list3`

```
setdiff(setdiff(list1, list2), list3)
```

This can look cleaner with the `%>%` pipe operator from `magrittr`

```
library(magrittr)
list1 %>% setdiff(list2) %>% setdiff(list3)
```

or you can define your own binary operator alias for `setdiff`

```
`%-%` <- setdiff
list1 %-% list2 %-% list3
```

or if you have a bunch of lists, you can do them all at once with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(setdiff, list(list1, list2, list3))
```

Comment: Same logic in the 'verse can be ```list(list1, list2, list3) %>% reduce(`setdiff`)```

Answer (score 1):

Try using conditional indexing:

```
list_final <- list1[!(list1 %in% list2) & !(list1 %in% list3)]

> list_final
[1] "ago" "aia" "alb" "are" "arg" "arm" "asm" "ata" "atf"
```